# Hide Protected Columns from another sheet with VBA

Tags: vba

Hell all,

I have an excel file with 2 sheets, and in sheet1 on cell C6 I have a value that changes automatically with a formula. And my goal is to hide columns Y:AN or AQ:BF on sheet2 if C6 on sheet1 is 3 or 2 respectively. I applied the code below, but doesnt work when I protect sheet2.

Any Help?

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Range("C6").Value = "2" Then
    Folha2.Columns("AQ:BF").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Folha2.Columns("Y:AN").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
  
    ElseIf Range("C6").Value = "3" Then
    Folha2.Columns("Y:AN").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
   Folha2.Columns("AQ:BF").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

    Else
    Folha2.Columns("AQ:BF").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Folha2.Columns("Y:AN").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Please, try using `Folha2.Unprotect pass` (`pass` being a string variable representing password) immediatelly after `Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()`, followed by `Folha2.Protect pass` before `End Sub`.

Comment: Thaks DaneDuru, it worked perfectly

Comment: Glad I could help.